# How to use JavascriptExecutor instead of send_keys in Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, textarea, sendkeys

I have written a script in python using send_key to type some text in a textarea on this [webpage](http://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/translate.html). However, it is really slow to use send_key as my text is really chunky.

```
from selenium import webdriver

text = "gckugcgaygartty"
link_url ="http://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/translate.html"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.get(link_url)

driver.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea").clear()
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea").send_keys("gckugcgaygartty")
```

I then tried to replace the send_keys with execute_script() like following but it didn't work (no errors but nothing changed on the webpage), could anyone give me some advice please?

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('main_form').getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].click()")



driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('main_form').getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].setAttribute('value', 'gckugcgaygartty' )")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Modification** : Changed setAttribute function with value property

**Use following Code :**

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value='your_lengthy_data'")
```

## OR

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('main_form').getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value='your_lengthy_data'")
```